# Looking for a better choice for real time push notification with PHP

Tags: php, comet, long-polling, ape

I want to implement real time push notifications from php to my project. i already testet 2 possible ways.

1. long polling the mysql database -> very poor performance, cause the query is big
2. long polling memcache and push via php -> poor performance
3. Ajax Push Engine -> seems not so easy to come along with... but comes with PHP integration

Does anyone know a better way?
Maybe there is some similar to memcache which alows Pushing?

Comment: I am sure you will find additional suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=comet+php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hosted service such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) (who I work for) might be a good solution for you. We offer a [JavaScript library](http://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start) for you to embed in your web pages and a REST API (and an easy to use [PHP publisher library](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries#php)) so you can push data from your own servers and into your web pages.

I've also put together a list of other [real-time technologies](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide) so you can have a look at the other options that might be available to you.